# Control a SciChart scrollbar manually

Tags: scichart

I'm attempting to make a custom overview with pan/zoom scroll bar.  The problem is, the data in the chart is not the total viewable amount of data (which I have stored in my own buffers) so I need to control the drawing manually.  I have this working using textboxes, I have a start point and an end point which causes my primary chart surface to zoom out to the range specified from my buffers.

Now I need to bind these integer properties to the grips of the scroll bar, but it seems if you don't bind them to the chart's axis they send you to a break mode.  I don't want the scroll bar directly bound to an axis on the chart, is this not possible?

Comment: Hi Kevin, SO question asking guidelines require as much info as possible to reproduce a problem. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. The community can be quite brutal with down-voting if you don't follow the guidelines!

Comment: So why are the forums disabled then?  I was doing just fine there. Why switch over to a terrible system where people are only interested in votes instead of actually helping people?

Comment: Perhaps a discussion to take up by emailing SciChart?